# Android bzip2 Compression

Tags: php, android, bzip2

I am using bzip2 compression on my PHP Server for compressing text files using the `bzcompress` function. I can decompress it on the server using the `bzdecompress` function.

But I want to decompress the data in Android. Is there any function or technique to decompress bzip2 in Android programming, just like `bzdecompress` in PHP?